# ASP.Net -- monitors/lock or mutex

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, mutex, monitor, server-side

I have an **ASP.net** (c#) application, that has a portion of code that modifies a globally accessible resource (like a web.config file).  When modifying the resource, naturally, to prevent race conditions only one user is allowed at a time so I need to lock the code using a monitor:

lock(Global.globallyAccessibleStaticObject)
{
  //..modify resource
  //..save resource
}

I was satisfied with this locking approach but then I thought, what if this isn't enough? should i use a *mutex* instead?  I know a mutex is useful for inter-process locking (across many processes and applications), and thus slower, but given the nature of a deployed asp.net page (multiple requests at once across multiple app domains), is this necessary?

The answer it seems, would depend on how asp pages are handled on the server side.  I have done research regarding the http pipeline, app domain, thread pooling etc. but i remain confused as to whether it is necessary to implore inter-process locking for my synchronization, or is intra-process locking sufficient for a web app???

**Note**: I don't want to get caught up in the specific task because I want this question to remain general, as it can be relevant in many (mult-threading) scenarios.  Furthermore, I know there are more ways to accomplish these tasks (async handlers/pages, web services, etc) that I don't care about right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application only runs in one AppPool, then it is running in one physical w3wp.exe process, so the monitors/lock should be sufficient for guarding the shared resource.  With that strategy, you only need to protect across threads running in the same process.

Comment: Classic case where one should read other answers (like @patrickmcdonald's) before making a decision. Granted these answers are separated by several years.

Answer (score 3):

We encountered a situation in work where we had an IIS application configured to run in a single AppDomain but `lock` was not sufficient to protect access to a resource.

The reason we think this was happening is that IIS was recycling the AppDomain before the lock was released, and kicking off a new AppDomain, so we were getting conflicts.

Changing to use a `Mutex` has resolved this for us (so far).